# Finding how many vowels are in string

Tags: java

This is my code here, I am trying to find how many vowels are there in the string vowelCount and keepng track in a int count[]; so the string is ("black banana republic boots") and the output should be {4, 1, 1, 2, 1}. Is my math correct. If not whats wrong

```
class lab204 {

    public static String vowelCount() {
        String vowelCount[] = ("black banana republic boots"); 
        int count[];
        int counter = 0;
        for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) {
        if( vowelCount.charAt(i) == 'a' ) {
            counter++;
        } 
        if( vowelCount.charAt(i) == 'e' ) {
         counter++;
        } 
        if( vowelCount.charAt(i) == 'i' ) {
            counter++;
        } 
        if( vowelCount.charAt(i) == 'o' ) {
            counter++;
        } 
        if( vowelCount.charAt(i) == 'u' ) {
         counter++;
        } 
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: For one, your code doesn't compile. I would work on that first.

Comment: The question is: does it work? If not, be so kind to tell us where it fails.

Comment: I"m seeing s.length() but s isn't defined. Maybe you mean vowelCount? Also you are incrementing an array instead of adding to it.

Comment: @thedon15, there's a few things I'll touch on briefly. 1. `int count[]` isn't being used for anything. 2. `s.length`,`s.charAt`, no where in your method is there a string called `s` so your `for` loop isn't traversing through anything. 3. Are you intending for `s` to be passed through as the parameter? 4. Your method is of type `String` so it must return a string.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code won't compile. This is because you are creating an array incorrectly. Note that you don't need an array, unless you want to count multiple strings at once.

```
public static String vowelCount() {

    //Does not need to be an array
    String sentence = "black banana republic boots";

    //Create your array to count 5 vowels
    int[] vowelCount = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    for( int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++ ) {

        //Don't forget to check for uppercase too!
        if( sentence.charAt(i) == 'a' || sentence.charAt(i) == 'A' ) {
            vowelCount[0]++;
        } 
        if( sentence.charAt(i) == 'e' || sentence.charAt(i) == 'E' ) {
            vowelCount[1]++;
        } 
        if( sentence.charAt(i) == 'i' || sentence.charAt(i) == 'I' ) {
            vowelCount[2]++;
        } 
        if( sentence.charAt(i) == 'o' || sentence.charAt(i) == 'O' ) {
            vowelCount[3]++;
        } 
        if( sentence.charAt(i) == 'u' || sentence.charAt(i) == 'U' ) {
            vowelCount[4]++;
        } 
    }
}
```

I'm assuming you don't know much about arrays, so I suggest reading up on them [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Also, your function is declared to return a string, when it seems like you really want to return the array with the count of the vowels. Change your function declaration like so:

```
public static int[] vowelCount() {
```

And at the end of your function, after the for loop, return the `vowelCount` array:

```
public static int[] vowelCount() {
    String sentence = "black banana republic boots";
    int[] vowelCount = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        //If statements
        //...
    } //End of for loop

    //Return the array counting the vowels
    return vowelCount;
} //End of function
```

Answer (score 0):

please fill in the blanks

```
public static String vowelCount() {
    String s = ("black banana republic boots"); //test string
    int count[] = new int[__]; //to use an int array for counting

    for( int i=0; i<s.length(); i++ ) { //looking at test string, one char at a time
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'a' ) {
        count[0]++; //increment the first array element
    } 
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'e' ) {
     ___________ //increment the second array element
    } 
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'i' ) {
       ___________ //...
    } 
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'o' ) {
        __________ //...
    } 
    if( s.charAt(i) == 'u' ) {
     _____________
    } 
  }

}
```

Comment: Its great to add an explanation for your code and things you have done rightly to make it easier for everyone to understand and helps the questioner to know his/her mistake

Comment: i am expecting TS to do a bit of work first but like you said, I should put in some explanation

Answer (score -1):

Some points:

**1)If else when it has one line it doen't need {} brackets**

2)Here is a sample code for your situation

```
public class VowelTester {

char[] vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'};



/** Check for vowels 
 * @param sample
 * @return array containing the counter of each vowel [a,e,i,o,u]
 */
public int[] checkForVowels(String sample) {
    int[] array = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < sample.length(); i++) {
        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'a')
            array[0] += 1;

        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'e')
            array[1] += 1;

        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'i')
            array[2] += 1;

        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'o')
            array[3] += 1;

        if (sample.charAt(i) == 'u')
            array[4] += 1;

    }

    System.out.println("a:"+array[0]+" e:"+array[1]+" i:"+array[2]+" o:"+array[3]+" u:"+array[4]);

    return array;
}


  public static void main(String[] args){
    new VowelTester().checkForVowels("Find out how many vowels i have");
  }
}
```